# Hover buttons that are not triggered by touch input

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a website with the above interface. A gallery of images with some description.
I need an overlay with buttons when hovered with the mouse, but touching should not trigger button clicks.

**Desired behaviour:**

- Mouse & touch: You can click on the element and it brings you to the details page
- Mouse only: When you hover the element, buttons appear with shortcut functions (but you can still click next to the buttons to click the element)

**Problem:**
If I set the buttons to `display: none;` and on `:hover` to `display: block;` the touch event is also received by buttons, even though they shouldn't be visible in that moment.

The solution would ideally be CSS only.

**Note:** I could of course disable the hover on smaller devices, but I don't want that since more and more laptops become touch enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it by applying three little tricks:**
(1) I move the buttons out of the way, hide them by overflow: none, add a transition of 0.001s (= instant) and a delay of 50ms.
→ When you touch, the buttons are not yet there (thanks to the delay) but 50ms is fast enough to (almost) look like a normal hover effect.

(2) I used pointer-events *none* on the button container (and *auto* on the buttons)
→ You can click anywhere next to the buttons

(3) The container is not the clickable element, because apparently links can't be nested 
→ Button container is positioned absolutely for the overlay effect

**Example:**

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .container{
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content{
        display: inline-block;
        background: orange;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .buttonWrapper{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: rgba(160,160,160,0.8);
        pointer-events: none;
        transition-duration: transform 0.001s;
        transition-delay: 50ms;
    }

    .buttonWrapper a{
        padding: 10px;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .container:hover .buttonWrapper{
        top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="container" >
    <a class="content" href="#clickedContent">
        I am some clickable content
    </a>
    <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <br>
        <a href="#clickedButton1">Link 1</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#clickedButton2">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```